# HBase, mongoDB, Cassandra - overhead on small cluster, small data

Tags: mongodb, cassandra, hbase, database

Ok,this systems are scalable with respect to nr of nodes and big amount of data.

But how about the overhead involved, if I use this systems on a small cluster (5-10 nodes), and on a small amount of data, processing/storing  on a scale of a couple of gigabytes? Or on a smaller data, like hundreds of MB ?
Are there better database systems to use for my cluster and my amount of data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A scalable solution usually pays a penalty required to scale over large data. The penalty is paltry compared to large data that you get to process. If you do not envisage processing data in Terabytes then you could do with a more responsive system that does not pay that penalty.

Use Sqlite database for smaller data. Frankly it depends on what other requirements/constraints you have.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably just use a single node mySQL server for this kind of data with the advantage of a full SQL capabilities, full ACID, mature tools etc.